# How to deal with non-formalized quasi-vote-to-close-comments?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons, comment-flags

In a comment to [this (clear, but zero-effort) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223642/how-to-split-a-integer-into-digits-and-then-multiply-the-numbers-in-python), a >15k user made the following request:

> Please no one give a full solution in code as this is obviously homework that OP would benefit from doing themselves

This comment has been upvoted three times. In its nature, it seemed to be similar to a "vote to close", but the problem was that the question was not closed properly. Since it wasn't closed properly, it started to attract answers of varying quality. Those answers all got downvoted by multiple users.

Since someone has already posted an answer, I thought that I could at least post a reasonably concise solution (hoping that either the OP learns something new, or the other answerers find something valuable in it). Moreover, the last time that I checked [the relevant Stack Overflow blog postings](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1), the suggestion seemed to be:

> But it’s totally cool to answer questions without giving a grilled poop sandwich about exactly what’s allowed.

(One might question whether this is the most eloquent formulation, but the meaning is clear: providing good answers to bad questions should be OK, at least that's what I understood?)

So, I posted an answer too, and also got downvoted, then deleted my answer.

A few hours later, some 26-rep user (who could not see all the downvoted and deleted answers) posted yet another solution. That solution had the most nested loops among all the answers, so at least it didn't seem like the most concise one.

Result:

- Three deleted valid answers
- Total of six downvotes on those answers
- A really long and cumbersome two-nested-loops answer as the only survivor.
- Question still not closed
- Eight downvotes and two counter-upvotes on a zero-effort question

**Screenshot (most names changed):**

[image: Swamp of death]

**Question**

What should I do with such "not-quite-VtC"-comments? Temporarily keeping bad questions "somewhat-half-closed" by a rain of downvotes just doesn't seem right.

- Flag the comment? (as what?)
- Write another comment that says "No, close as 'Too Broad'" (it's not really "too broad", but I don't know how else to close the gimmetehcodez).
- Both previous actions? (Write: "VtC as 'Too Broad'" + flag as 'No longer needed')
- Do something different entirely?

Such comments do not seem to align with the goal of creating good content and serving the future visitors (instead of providing personal tutoring to one particular user).

Any hints how to deal with such comments and how to clean up this mess would be appreciated.

**Update:** I'd like to explicitly *exclude* a similar situation where a golden badge holder with a dupe-hammer requests to wait with answers because he or she suspects that the question is a duplicate and waits for clarification by the OP. The case with a golden badge holder is different, because (s)he is obviously trying to improve the average quality of the content on the website, whereas in the concrete example described above, the commenter requested to post answers that might be suboptimal from the point of view of the visitors who will read the answers in the future.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with the commenter who asked that no-one provide a full solution, I just think it would be best expressed differently. They should be appealing to the OP to improve their question and/or to make an effort, rather than appealing to everyone else on how much they should help. Readers are allowed to help on questions where no effort was expended (though they will sometimes get DV for doing so).

Comment: @halfer Since I've spent quite a bit of time inventing homework exercises and correcting them, I can empathize with this attitude. On the other hand, there is [also this opinion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#comment454578_334823). But I'm less concerned about how to deal with homework exercises, I'd rather want to understand how to deal with such comments that neither close nor allow to answer properly. Keeping questions "quasi-closed-for-a-while" by a rain of downvotes doesn't seem constructive.

Comment: I'm totally in favor of closing zero-effort homework dumps. And that "new policy"...  let's just say that policy is highly controversial, and *not* the result of a community feedback process.

Comment: Well, you know the OP asked this to win a coding competition.  Your answer completely ignored that angle, it did not consider perf at all.  Why would anybody consider that helpful?  Lost opportunity btw, comparing the recursive solution against an iterative one would be the real value, possibly for you personally as well.

Comment: That's what happen when both contradicting "rules" (not really rules) "help everyone regardless of OP" and "people get annoyed if OP doesn't show effort" exist.

Comment: @HansPassant The OP didn't say in the question that it's for a competition, and (s)he didn't ask anything about performance. If I'm not missing anything, the performance is mostly determined by the very first call to `str` on an integer, after that, the size of the number should collapse rapidly. But I digress...

Comment: Did anyone else notice the alarming number of comments that really could (and even should) have been answers on this question?  The non-highlighted portion of the comment you pointed out was an answer!

Comment: @ryanyuyu If this was posted as an answer, I would have downvoted it, because it does not provide the shortest and clearest solution for the hundreds of users that will look at it after the question is answered. It just seems to be unclear whether we should answer this or not. I don't know. I'm confused. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Note there is no "new policy". In particular, denying answers to non-closeable (including *quasi*-closeable questions) was never policy. Cf. [*Does the recent blog post on being less hostile contradict “How to Answer”'s advice on not answering bad questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366780/2751851), and especially [Brad Larson's answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366832/2751851).

Comment: Related list: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359866), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296159), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13864).

Comment: In related topics, as a gold-badge-holder I often leave "quasi-VTC" comments when I want the OP to edit to clarify if it is or is not a duplicate of a (set of) question before I use the hammer, but I also encourage people to not answer yet. I don't think that's what you are asking about, so maybe you can clarify this question one way or the other?

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't see any fundamental difference, to be honest. Whether you comment "Wait, don't answer this, looks like duplicate" (and then the crowd keeps downvoting everything), or whether you say "Wait, don't answer this question (in a particular manner), looks like homework" (+ crowd + downvotes), the situation looks conceptually similar. I'm not sure, wouldn't it be better instead of saying "Hold!" to just put the question "On Hold", isn't "put on hold" exactly for those cases? If you think that you can share some insights from the experiences with the dupehammer, feel free to share.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin that's fine too. I'm just suggesting that you edit your question to explicitly include or exclude this related example beyond just of topic questions

Comment: @Shepmaster I will update it, but I can update it both ways: including or excluding your case. *Do* you want to answer something? If yes, I will update the question accordingly. If no, I will find a good enough reason to exclude the dupe-hammer scenario. I'd be happy about both solutions. The original question is somewhat under-determined.

Comment: it's almost as if we don't have an existing flag system for problematic content. Why does this keep coming up? use the tools available to you.

Comment: @KevinB We do have the flag system, but I don't even understand which content should be considered "problematic" here? Should I flag the question as "rude and abusive", because it's a copy-pasted coding exercise from another website? Should I flag the comment because it attempts to bypass the VtC-system? Should I flag all the answers, because they facilitate getting answers to really bad questions, thereby providing an incentive to ask even more bad questions? Should I leave it as-is, even though I think that I could provide an answer that is better than some of the already given answers?

Comment: No, the comment is chatty. it isn't a request for clarification. past that, nothing else unless you find the question fitting of a close reason or a downvote. That should be the end of it, act on it, move on

Comment: Relevant FAQ: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: "*So, I posted an answer too, and also got downvoted, then deleted my answer*" - why did you delete it?! If you answered with what you considered of as helpful, despite already seeing that some people discourage answering, you should not be afraid of their downvotes, and **you should not delete your answer**. If you agree with the opinion that the question should not be answered, don't post it in the first place.

Comment: @Bergi I thought it was somewhat useful. At least two other people thought it was not useful. I counted the votes, and concluded that the answer is generally considered to be not useful. Since it was considered not useful, I deleted it. If the site is community moderated, who am I to disregard the opinions of other community members? As you see, I found the situation confusing enough to ask a question on meta.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You're the author of the answer, only your opinion matters on the question whether it should stay up. The community would delete your answer (by the means of elected moderators) only in case of severe problems. (Also, in general you should ignore the casual downvote in case there is nothing obviously wrong with the answer)

Comment: @Bergi AFAIK, mods are not the only mechanism used by the system to delete bad questions. I can't give the exact reference, but I think that I've read somewhere that bad downvoted questions can be deleted automatically, but aren't deleted if there are at least two answers. Thus, my answer would interfere with the attempts of the community to get the question automatically deleted. I don't want to hinder anyone who tries to get rid of bad questions.

Comment: This reminds me of [this answer detailing how different groups of users feel about each other](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/1711796). We should probably address the problematic behaviour, but that's like sticking a band-aid on a broken arm - it isn't going to change the underlying problem or how that makes users feel.

Comment: This seems unusual behaviour on the Python tag to me. One option would be to post in the Python chat room (not as a request to close) and see what the people there think. It's an active chat room, though maybe not so much in your timezone. In any case, I would have expected more decisive action; either it gets closed or it gets answered, but not closing a question and throwing downvotes everywhere is plain dumb.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin (Yes, there's the question roomba, and there are spam flags, but I was focusing on your answer). My main point was that you should stand by your opinion, whether it is a minority or not. You should not change your mind just because of votes.

Comment: @Bergi [part-1] I would agree if we were talking about something technical, like a mathematical proof or some algorithm implementation: there I usually have enough tools to make sure that I don't make any major errors, so I can stand by my "opinion" indefinitely if I want to, as for example [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801698/scala-parallel-collections/49806743#49806743), where I got downvoted apparently because the OP failed to compile the solution with his antediluvian compiler version, and some nonsense-blah-blah-answer got upvoted instead.

Comment: @Bergi [part-2] But this doesn't work as soon as the votes are used to signal whether a question is appropriate or not: then the quality of the code doesn't really matter. I still think that the solution itself was OK, but what's the point in "standing by my opinion" about the quality of the answer, if the quality of the answer isn't at all what the downvoters are judging? I didn't delete the answer because I didn't like the code in it. I deleted it because it turned out that I'm in a different game with strange rules that I don't want to play. That's why I'm asking the meta-Q here.

Comment: As someone who sees a lot of custom close vote reasons, this comment does not look like an attempt to close vote or custom close vote reason at all to me, it just looks like a comment asking people not to answer.

Comment: Please don't pretend that The Blog Post is policy. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Alright, maybe "policy" is not the right word. But "opinion of a Stack Overflow employee" doesn't seem like the right formulation either, at least the repeated use of the pronoun "we" in the blog post suggested that it was not merely a personal opinion of one single employee. I replaced the formulation by the vague "relevant Stack Overflow blog posting", I hope we can at least agree that it was a blog post, and that the blog post was somewhat relevant for this question.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

*climbs atop soapbox, groaning*

I agree that this is problematic behaviour, and a very slippery slope. This has little to do with a *Programming Q&A*, it's a judgemental mob. Yes, the question is pretty darn lazy, fine. However, it *is* a programming problem, it's a pretty well scoped problem, it's even a fairly generic problem that others could benefit from.

The only reason we're "denying" giving an answer is that we perceive the OP doesn't deserve it. **And that is dangerous.** So we're not going to answer if the question *appears to be* a homework question by a student? Who are we going to deny answers next? Askers who have tried for less than 30 minutes? 60 minutes? 3 days? I've ranted about this [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341467/476), but you *can't prove effort.* We're asking people to "show effort," but that is not an end in itself. It's mostly so we can better diagnose where they're stuck. Not so we can judge whether they're worthy of an answer.

*falls off soapbox*

So, think:

- Is the question **answerable** within the scope of the site?
- Has it already been answered? Then find a duplicate.
- Could it be phrased better? Then edit it.
- Do you have an answer? Then post it.
- Have others posted an answer? Then **evaluate the answer on its own merits**, not based on whether it was posted in response to a question whose poster you deem unworthy of help.
- Should the OP be slapped on the wrist for not doing their homework? Then leave a comment, and try not to be rude.
- If the same question had been posted by somebody else phrased slightly differently, would you have done anything differently? If so, [why?!](http://www.optimum7.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Jackie-Chan-I-Cannot.jpg)

#### What about comments dissuading anyone from posting an answer?

Ignore them. You don't need to bend to group pressure. Apply your own good judgement. Stand by what you think matters. If the comment is causing trouble or is superfluous, flag it as such.

Comment: Eric Lippert's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223642/how-to-split-a-integer-into-digits-and-then-multiply-the-numbers-in-python?noredirect=1#comment87465038_50223642) on the question is spot-on. "These kinds of problems are exercises in _breaking complicated problems down into simpler problems_." The OP is better helped by being taught how to split the problem up, than by an answer on the question.

Comment: Then write *that* as an answer!

Comment: You really think other people could benefit from it? If you want to learn,  you should read the tutorial _and solve simpler problems_ (<-- this part was typed in after the comment above was written), not search for code that directly solves your problem.

Comment: Then write an answer that tells the OP how to tackle these kinds of problems!

Comment: Also for the bullet points: stepping away and not replying at all is a valid option.

Comment: 'Then write an answer that tells the OP how to tackle these kinds of problems' ..and then link all the other no-effort homework/quiz questions as duplicates to that one?

Comment: @Martin Perfectly good option.

Comment: So, are you saying that answering requirements dump Q's is ok?

Comment: @deceze I suspect that it would not go well.  Not getting a dedicated answer to a question tends to cause an attack of 'unwelcoming'.

Comment: @Martin Worse than this swamp question here?

Comment: @deceze ................. probably not, no:)

Comment: @chris Most "RDQs" are highly specific and too detailed, they're too broad and virtually useless for anyone else. Those: no. This specific question here is a pretty generic algorithm and perfectly answerable.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Personally, I, and many other users (I think) will not answer such questions, because I think there is no point in answering them. If you still want to answer them, it's up to you, but do consider if it worths the time you put in.

Comment: @chris A lot of RDQs can be closed as a dupe of a generic reference. E.g. there's a bunch of canonicals for how to sort arrays and such.

Comment: @deceze "highly specific" contradicts with "too broad". I can't understand your comment.

Comment: I would be surprised if there is not an exact duplicate out there.  I do have a problem, though, with putting more effort into finding dupes than the OP did:(

Comment: @user As in, ten bullet points of what the program must do. That is at once too broad, and also too specific to the OP. Questions which are simply too specific are often "how do I sort this array", which can be dupe-closed.

Comment: @Martin If there exists a dupe, it means the question itself is a legitimate question on SO; otherwise there'd be no dupe. And you don't have to invest energy if you don't want to, just walk away and let it wither on the vine then.

Comment: @user Note that "too specific" isn't an official close reason *anymore*, but it can inform your decision whether you feel like investing time to produce an answer.

Comment: **Information**: The question had been closed as "Too broad" meanwhile.

Comment: *ba-dum ching* :D

Comment: This is all very good and nice, but I'm still not sure what to do about comments that tell me not to answer the question in a way that is most beneficial to the broadest audience possible. Answer the question, then watch my own rep drop, simply because I wanted to demonstrate that everyone deserves an answer? No, thanks. That wasn't my intent anyway.

Comment: @deceze 'just walk away' yup - exactly what I would have done.  Vote, next...  Swamp-draining is just too much hard work for no reward.

Comment: In my experience "highly specific and too detailed, they're too broad and virtually useless for anyone else." Q's overlap with Q's that are answerable, usually with a few generic techniques.  I guess you mean we should subjectively judge an A will be useful to future readers, and base a decision to answer on that.  That's a slippery slope...

Comment: @Andrey I would first and foremost declare them as "invalid", i.e. you can ignore them. Flag them if they seem to cause trouble.

Comment: @chris You should judge the question on its own merits. If it's clearly outside the scope of SO, vote to close it with a legitimate reason. If beyond that you don't feel like answering for whatever reason, just don't. Some of the most useful answers on this site sprang from someone spontaneously typing a couple of hundred useful words into a textbox in response to some mediocre question.

Comment: @user my main criteria for answering any Q is "is it interesting (to me)"

Comment: @chris Good yardstick in my book.

Comment: @deceze If you propose to "flag them if they seem to cause trouble", could you please add it to your answer so that it's clearly visible? Next time I come across something like that, I will then flag them with a link to your answer, then maybe the mods can comment on that too ;)

Comment: @deceze yes, I already do all that.  In fact some of my most highly upvoted A's have been on contentious Q's that have been closed and reopened.  It just that this apparent softening of attitude to borderline Q's leaves me feeling uneasy

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Done!

Comment: @chris The attitude of judging based on perceived circumstances surrounding the posting of the question is equally troubling to me. I'd like to get to a baseline of *do something positive or just do nothing* rather than stupid downvote wars as in this case.

Comment: @chrisneilsen It's up to you. It doesn't hurt anyone either.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Can you explain how "providing the full code" = "benefit the broadest audience"? | If someone find it useful, they will upvote your answer. If you don't receive any upvotes, it's not useful.

Comment: @user202729 "Highly specific" and "too broad" don't contradict each other, because broadness has at least two dimensions: (1) How much ground an adequate answer would have to cover; and (2) How much code an adequate answer would have to include. A question might be very specific with respect to the first dimension, but too broad with respect to the second one. Also, consider questions of the "Write a personalised tutorial for me" kind: they are too broad precisely because they have to cover too much ground to satisfy the very specific needs of the asker.

Comment: @user202729 I wouldn't go so far to put an equality sign between those two phrases. But I think it would be fair to say that in general it holds that "providing the shortest and cleanest solution" =/= "writing a lengthy customized tutorial that hints at the solution", those are just two separate goals. In some cases, what "benefits the OP" is not exactly the same as what benefits all those who search for a solution later. If I click on SO answers, I usually don't expect to see any pedagogically optimized step-by-step tutorials with hints.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Then what kind of "answer" are you going to provide? (I can't see deleted posts)

Comment: @user202729 My answer was a simple one-liner solution. I did explain every part of it briefly, but it clearly wasn't "pedagogically helpful", in the sense that it didn't leave anything to do for the OP. It was a "spoiler", if you will. But again, SO is a Q&A-site, not a Q@-pedagogically-helpful-hints-and-puzzles site. Providing partial solutions that "point in the right direction" can be fun too, but it's quite different.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I didn't find the second half of the comment spot-on. I don't remember whether this was the main reason, but when I saw the "helpful hint" that said **"There are only 90 of them; You can test them all"**, and then imagined the OP writing down an ~180 lines long if-else to handle the case `n = 2`, I could have thought that a one-liner solution would be appropriate here... I don't know what exactly that comment meant, it could be misinterpreted easily.

Comment: @jpp: That wasn't a grammar error, just [a different (and frankly more logical) style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#Order_of_punctuation).

Comment: @MichaelMyers, Interesting take. But I would link to the [SE question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147451/can-a-mid-sentence-quote-have-a-comma-outside-the-quotation-marks). I upvoted the second answer there :).

Comment: @deceze You are right, this is a programming Q&A. Where did you find a _programming_ question in the link posted? All I see is an off-topic abstract math problem. Just because something can be solved with programming doesn't make it on-topic.

Comment: @Lundin Well, the math on that problem is simple, and the OP already has the math answer. The (implicit) question is how to *code* that in [tag:python]. Again, yes, it's a lazy question and could be improved a lot, but then it totally makes for an answerable programming question. What it's certainly not is a free ticket to allow a mob to downvote valid answers based on the assumption that the question *shouldn't* be answered.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I just repeat what you said. You provided the full code (if I understood correctly), and you said that your action "benefits the broadest audience". [​](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299412)

Comment: @user202729 What? Where did I say *that*?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin "I'm still not sure what to do about comments that tell me not to answer the question in a way that is most beneficial to the broadest audience possible." + "My answer was a simple one-liner solution." | Then what did you want to say? Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: @user202729 Those are two more or less independent statements: someone commented, someone else answered with a one-liner. I don't see any logical way to infer the statement that some `action "benefits the broadest audience"`. I only said that I mostly ignored the plea in the comment, and tried to provide an answer that is as complete as possible. From that it does not follow that I've somehow managed to write an answer that actually "benefits the broadest audience".

Comment: `The only reason we're "denying" giving an answer is that we perceive the OP doesn't deserve it`: what if you can take the subjective perception out of the equation, because the question is copy-pasted verbatim from a publicly available on-line coding competition website? Would it be acceptable if someone copy-pastes 100 questions from "Codewars"? I can assure you, all those questions are short, clear, not too broad, and about programming. I admit, I digress somewhat... That's not about how to deal with comments.

Comment: "Then write that as an answer" - **no**; because it's not an answer, it's an *explanation of what is wrong with the question*. It **needs more focus** (as we said in 2018, it was **too broad**). The new wording captures the issue better: the problem isn't the amount of code that needs to be written for an answer, it's the *number of tasks* that code conceptually has to perform (more than one).

Answer (score 11):

Basically, what you have is a group of users trying to manually reinstate the "Too Localized" close reason. Back in the day, that question would be closed for being too localized for the specific user. That the problem was so narrow in scope that any answers would be of little value to the "not that person" department.

What you do with such a comment is up to you. You can follow the current rules and answer anyway. Yes, the Too Localized people will likely putatively downvote your answer, but you provided an answer that will serve the Audience of One. Feel good about that and move on.

Or you can choose to agree that answering localized questions is a waste of time, that it does little for serving Stack Overflow's broader goal of providing knowledge that is broadly useful. And therefore, you'd just move on of your own accord.

It's up to you.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it was "too localized": the question seemed to be some kind of puzzle or online-competition, and it also does look like a "classic" basic programming exercise, so it probably would be useful to a much larger audience than most of the "normal" questions that I usually answer. As I mentioned above, it was rather "overt request for code", because the OP simply copy-pasted the question from this online-coding-competition site.

Comment: I don't know, honestly, why then can't there be a simple "gimmetehcodez" close reason? It occurs so often! This question is not too broad, it's not unclear, and it's not "why is this code not working" (because there is no code at all). Every time I encounter a "gimmetehcodez", I have to google the meta site, to understand what the current close reason is. If it is an attempt to "manually reinstantiate {some close reason}", then why is it not formalized as an actual proper close reason, why cannot those 6 downvotes be converted into an orderly 'Closed'?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin For historical background, cf. [*Closing changes: on hold, unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/242059) (Meta.SE).

Comment: @duplode Yes, thanks, I think I've came across those meta-pages several times, every time I re-read them, I feel only more confused. As this example shows, the close-reasons seem to not always reflect the actual behavior of the users (so they feel forced to downvote answers, because they can't find a suitable close reason). But I'll carefully re-read the linked question, maybe I will be able to memorize it this time.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin "the close-reasons seem to not always reflect the actual behavior of the users" + "the site is moderated by the community" >>= confusion.

Comment: @user202729 *Without getting into the specific merits of "too localized"*: As an user-moderator, there are lots of questions that I want to be closed, *and* there are lots of questions that I want to remain open. If a broadly applicable close reason is replaced by a set of reasons with a narrower scope that are less likely to be (mis)used to close questions I believe should remain open, I will see that as an improvement.

Comment: I would have understood "too localized" to mean, in essence, "the question could not feasibly be used as a duplicate to close *someone else's* question, for reasons *other than* a lack of focus or clarity". In particular, because of an idiosyncratic logic error, that can't be searched for (someone else who made the same mistake would not know what the problem is, and thus couldn't search about it; nor would an accurate description of the wrong thinking pattern make a viable search query).

Answer (score 3):

> It's not really "too broad", but I don't know how else to close the gimmetehcodez

*Lack of effort is not a close reason*. Low-effort questions often turn out to be too broad -- because they demand too much code to be written, or an excessive amount of ancillary explanations to be given to make the asker able to understand the actual answer -- or closeable for some of the other reasons. If a low-effort question is not closeable due to one of the *existing* reasons, it should not be closed. In such cases, feel free to downvote it, or to ignore it, or to answer it in the way you consider to be most useful.

(Do note that encouraging the OP of a requirement dump question to say more about which specific difficulties they are facing while trying to solve the problem is often a sensible thing to do, *even if the question doesn't merit closure*, simply because that makes for a better question.)

---

One rather serious difficulty with quasi-vote-to-close comments is that *closing is generally a matter of editorial judgement*, over which there can be reasonable disagreement even among folks trying their best at enforcing site policies and guidelines. That is especially true for reasons such as "too broad", for which there is no objective yardstick to point to. If I think a question should remain open, I can't coerce you to retract your close vote; if I think it should be closed, I can't coerce you to delete your answer. That must hold even if I'm accompanied by a group of like-minded users, lest we end up acting as ["a judgemental mob"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367540/2751851).

(Note that it is fine to, say, leave a comment pointing out why a question should not be closed, if you think it is attracting unjustified close votes. Adequate behaviour in such cases is primarily a matter of circumspection, of knowing where and when to stop.)

Comment: "Lack of effort is not a close reason" - I understand the reasoning behind that, I even agree, mostly. If we are talking about long difficult questions with 200 lines of code dumps, where it would be hard to figure out what OP's problem is: OK, agree, lack of effort is not a close reason, leave it open. If nobody dares to try to help, because the question is prepared so poorly, then it's just OP's own fault. But this argument seems to fail spectacularly for funny little code-golf-like puzzles where zero effort is required to make the question entertaining.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin [you may want to read this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/4639281)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin 200-line dump questions are *very* often closeable as either "too broad", "unclear" or "off-topic/MCVE" -- it's just that, there being no blanket rule, the decision has to be made on a case by case basis. As for the tiny puzzles, you can still give feedback and try to drive improvements (by downvoting and/or leaving an actionable comment) even without voting to close.

Comment: @TinyGiant Shog is spot-on there: "Effort is useful when it produces *results*."

Answer (score -2):

The other answers deal with the specifics nicely. I'm just going to explain the phases I go through. I'm getting quite good at writing downvoted answers (~1% of my answers are downvoted, many times due to question quality concerns), so I speak from experience.

**Feel free to disregard the comment**

The comment does not clarify or ask for clarification regarding the question. You may read it. But it is also safe to disregard. Comments are, after all, ephemeral.

**Answer if you feel you can add value**

If you feel you can add value, answer the question. One person may believe it's impossible to add value to a poor question. Another might be believe it is possible. The good thing about SO is YOU get to make the decision. Do what you think makes a good Q&A.

**Be ready to accept downvotes and don't let it faze you**

I seem to specialize in answering questions which get downvoted or, occasionally, deleted. Especially when advised not to answer. Revenge downvotes for defying the puritans are typical. If a question I answer is deleted, I might go back and write an embellished Q&A.

Comment: That's an interesting perspective. "Beating" the "puritans" by points might be easy, because you get 5x as much rep for every upvote than for a downvote. But are you sure that the "puritans" won't take their "revenge" by simply leaving sooner or later? Getting some upvotes vs. annoying "the puritans" seems like a not entirely trivial trade-off to me.

Comment: I understand that you are talking about "revenge downvotes from the puritans". I'm just saying that if puritans downvote you frequently, then they are probably somewhat unhappy frequently, which, in the long term, might lead to the situation when they consider to participate less, or to leave entirely. And, as I said, getting some reputation points at the expense of the puritans being annoyed is a trade-off that I'm not ready to consider, therefore I rather try not to get any downvotes. I'm not sure what in my comment invoked the impression that something is unclear.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, Apologies, I understand you now. I guess I don't believe that's the case. The puritans (and I don't mean the term in a derogatory way; literally, more rule-based) would have left a long time ago if they require SO to satisfy their standards. They usually don't care about the -1. There are plenty of people like me who don't heed the -2 either.

Answer (score -3):

I don't agree with any of the posted answers so far, and I'm baffled how everyone seems to think this question is fine.

**The question is a *math* problem, not a *programming* problem. This is a programming Q&A and there is no programming question to answer.**

It should be closed as off-topic or too broad. Period. There is not just a "lack of effort", the question is not even on-topic for this site! The question may or may not be on-topic on the math or comp. science sites.

In addition "reading material on how stuff like this works would also be appreciated" is a request for off-site resources, which is also off-topic.

The only thing related to programming here is the Python tag, which we can only interpret as "gimme teh pyton codez". Adding that tag does not make it a programming question. Adding the OP's attempts to implement it in Python would on the other hand make the question perfectly on-topic. That's the *only* way to fix this question and so it can only be fixed by the OP.

This question should have been down-voted and closed much faster. Anyone attempting to answer too broad off-topic questions instead of flagging/closing deserve all the down votes they get.

So the core problem here is not the comments, but a complete failure by multiple high rep users and moderators to close the off-topic question fast enough.

Comment: Why you think it is not a programming problem? The OP obviously can execute the algorithm in his or her head or on paper or in the question. OP just can't figure out how to write code that executes this algorithm automatically. It's still a bad question for not having an MCVE - the most obvious way to show lack of effort. But either way the question is about programming I think.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi "How to write code in Python" is indeed a programming question but that doesn't make it on-topic and it's of course a horribly broad question too. _Why_ can't they turn this into code? What part of the Python language is it that they don't understand how to use? This needs to be specified by the OP or otherwise the "correct answer" is to copy/paste a whole Python programming book into SO.

Comment: *"Anyone attempting to answer too broad off-topic questions instead of flagging/closing deserve all the down votes they get."* – And ***this*** is what I strongly object to. The rest I'm not even necessarily all disagreeing with.

Comment: @deceze It is a fact that a whole lot of users systematically answer easy FAQ questions instead of closing them, which is egocentric. They want more rep instead of improving the site, which is rude. And therefore they deserve downvotes, not upvotes. That aside, people are deadly tired of the flood of bad questions. SO the company does not solve the problem, if anything they encourage it to get more traffic. As a result we get "lynch mobs", a side effect that happens whenever an official system is broken, like or not.

Comment: I also strongly object to the idea of a "rep whore". I consider it a baseless insult. **We are here to answer questions.** Yes, some of those will be easy. So what? Now you're not only going to apply standards to what should be asked, but also what should be answered? Where does it end? No, again, [Objection](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/-rPYF_LJmgs/maxresdefault.jpg).

Comment: And yes, the flood of bad questions *is* a problem. Let's solve that. Let's not create a civil war in the meantime of "rep whores" vs. lynch mobs. Lynch mobs don't stop bad questions.

Comment: @deceze Of course we have standards for what should be asked, why do you think we have moderators in the first place? One such standard is that we shouldn't ask the same question over and over. Therefore the duplicate system exists. Experienced users are expected to know of close votes and duplicates. The whole idea behind self-moderation is that users contribute. So what are you propagating for here, a site with no user moderation?

Comment: @Lundin Moderate the question, yes! Don't punish users for **answering**, if your only arguments for doing so are that it will stop bad questions (it's never been proven to do so, and bad questions clearly haven't stopped coming) or that they're "rep whoring" (you're ascribing insulting motivation to people using the site as designed).

Comment: @deceze The whole point here is: why are those users writing answers _instead_ of moderating, as is expected of them? Or as in one case in the discussed post, one high rep user (>10k) is _both_ moderating _and_ answering, effectively saying that the question cannot be answered in its current form, yet at the same time answering it. How exactly does that lead to a better site and what kind of signal does it send to the OP? Explain to me why these users behave the way they do and why their behavior is exemplary, undeserving of loss of community reputation.

Comment: I don't know why people do what they do. They might have a different opinion from what they deem answerable than you. Charitably I would say the question happened to tickle their [fancy bone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367538/how-to-deal-with-non-formalized-quasi-vote-to-close-comments/367603?noredirect=1#comment586769_367540) and they felt like figuring out a one-liner to answer it. That is a lot of what SO is about and why people participate in it. If you vote to close the question instead, fine. If there's a majority of people thinking that, then it'll be closed.

Comment: The point is, it's a consensus-based platform. Consensus should be a democratic process in which the most upvoted action is the consensus. In this case, if 5 people come together to close the question, so be it. If other people answer the question, so be it. What downvoting answers is is mob behaviour, not democracy.

Comment: @deceze So you truly think that a veteran user telling a newbie that "your question is not a good fit for this site, it is too broad and cannot be answered" while at the same also telling them "here is the answer to your question" is doing the right thing? That we should allow them to continue treating new users like that? By downvoting that veteran user's answer we tell them that this is not an acceptable way to moderate questions on SO. Reputation is not all about technical value, it is also a measure of trust. I don't trust this user to moderate questions because of the posted answer.

Comment: Votes are supposed to work in a meritocratic way: you have good technical knowledge, your technical work is upvoted, this gives you status. And to readers votes indicate technical accuracy. It becomes very murky once you conflate community-status-punishment with that. Future readers will read that as an answer being technically inaccurate for some reason, when really the negative score indicates something completely different and more meta. **That is nonsense.** (cont.)

Comment: At least *do nothing!* An answer without votes doesn't get the poster anything. They have just wasted some time answering a question which will be closed and eventually deleted. That would be punishment enough. But if for whatever reason the question survives, perhaps because it is edited into shape, then there's a good answer there. As this example here demonstrates, downvoting answers as a tactic clearly doesn't benefit the site either. It leaves a bad question with decent answers deleted and a bad answer remaining. Yay, great accomplishment.

Comment: @deceze You are kind of missing the point. If a user decides that the question cannot be answered, then at the same time decides to answer still, how could that possibly be a good quality answer? Likely it was impossible to give a good answer to begin with.

Comment: And rep hunters aside, we also don't want to encourage bad quality questions. Answering a question is to encourage more of the same. That's what this all boils down to - some users having a quality standard where they think that the question should be closed, others having a lower quality standard, thinking that code begging is fine and should be rewarded. Votes are used to set the quality bar of the site - this and nothing else is the purpose of the whole vote/rep system.

Comment: I cannot speak as for why that one user thought a question unanswerable and answerable at once. – You have a thesis, that discouraging answers to bad questions will get rid of bad questions, and you accept a mess as in this case as a collateral to reach that goal via these means. I disagree that this thesis holds water to begin with, and I disapprove of the collateral damage that is caused by it. Clearly bad questions haven't gone away, and clearly that mess with the bad answer being the only remaining answer was very suboptimal. *Something* isn't working there.

Comment: Yes, we must close bad questions and preferably keep them from entering the system in the first place. No, I don't think this tactic of punishing answerers is the way to do it.

Comment: @deceze This question only ended up a mess because it wasn't moderated fast enough. Part of the reason why it wasn't moderated fast enough was users writing answers instead of moderating.

Comment: Agreed. Now, did downvoting answers fix that problem? Did it make people vote to close instead? Or did it just create confusing signals as to the answers' accuracy and cause a bunch of frustration?

Comment: @deceze We can't tell if it fixed the problem unless we sit next to the same users next time they are facing a crap question.

Comment: Well, there were 4 answers, plus at least one extra user that voted to close, so that should have made 5 close votes. Imma go ahead and say that tactic *didn't* work. – Even if, you could have done the same by leaving a comment urging individual users to vote to close without conflating the issue with votes meant for indicating technical merit.

Comment: @deceze And so the underlying problem is the core design of SO. The site mixes up technical quality/competence with moderator suitability and previligies. Yes, it is a dumb system. A better site would use two separate reputation systems, one for measuring technical competence and another for moderator suitability.

Comment: Agreed, it's a bit of a messy mix. Not sure you'd want to complicate it further with some additional orthogonal metric, but I agree on the core point. But this is not something to slug out within the questions or answers. I would equate that to discussing an argument on a Wikipedia page; just don't do it. This must be discussed right here and implemented by SE. And given The Blog Post™, now seems to be a great time to put forward suggestions.

Comment: How would you measure moderator suitability?

Comment: @deceze None of what we have done help to stop the bad questions 100%. That includes closing question / punishing answers. I don't think anyone can prove or disprove that one is more "effective at stopping bad questions" than others.

Comment: @user202729 Agreed. I do posit that punishing answers as a technique to stop bad questions does more harm than good. We are in agreement that "The Good" can't be measured either way, but The Harm is IMO quite manifest. Especially since it isn't the only technique, and in fact was never officially endorsed by anyone as a technique of any sort, let's stop doing it.

Comment: It's *definitely not* a math problem in any reasonably narrow sense. The fact that the task includes some bastardized arithmetics does not automatically make it a "math problem". On motivation: as I've already said elsewhere, the main motivation was probably the comment by a 500k user that apparently suggested to perform case-by-case analysis to cover the two-digit numbers. Furthermore, I didn't like the other answers (I didn't like the `int(x) * int(y)`, because casting to `int` was used twice, instead of doing it once in a generator expr, and I didn't like the explicit lambda).

Comment: [part-2] ... so I decided: if this is going to be answered anyway, one can at least use it as opportunity to show how to do it with the functions already defined in the standard library, and to make sure that the OP does not walk away with the impression that (s)he should do a 180-lines long case-by-case analysis for such a trivial task. On voting to close as off-topic: maybe I missed something, but does voting to close require the question to be "unanswerable"? If someone asks "Can horses fly?", the question is answerable by every 3-years-old, but it's still off-topic.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Using the same logic, if someone asks "I'm making a horse management program in Python. Here is a whole lot of information about the various horses: ..." then you should go ahead and write the whole program for him, because it is a clearly an answerable question. Ignoring that the question is actually about horses and not about specific programming problems.

Comment: @Lundin No, *using the same **logic***, from the statement "a question does not have to be unanswerable to be off-topic" I cannot infer "every theoretically answerable question must be answered". I think that in the example that you've given, most people would not have any problems to classify the question as "too broad". The problem with the short coding-competition one-liners (as in the question that started this discussion) is that they are short, clear, precise, not too broad, so they aren't closed properly, because there is no good 'gimmetehcodez' close-reason.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin We _had_ a "gimmetehcodez" close reason called "poster must demonstrate utter minimum of knowledge of the topic". SO the company took it away since it reduced code beggar traffic. And here we are some 5 years later drowning in code beggars still. One reason being code-beggar-huggers who keep giving the beggars fish instead of teaching them how to fish.

Comment: "Anyone attempting to answer too broad off-topic questions instead of flagging/closing deserve all the down votes they get." - contra deceze, this is the *best* idea in this answer. Any time someone attempts an answer for a question that should be closed, that inherently interferes with the normal operation of the site. But the main-site question was absolutely not *off topic*, nor a math question, although it was too broad. Unless you are thinking of "figure out the math needed to isolate digits", but that's not even the approach the commenter came up with!

Comment: (Last I checked, just for the record, the string splitting and converting approach will likely be more performant in Python. That way can use specialized routines under the hood that are optimized for the overall task of figuring out the digits are - for the purpose of creating the string representation - whereas the number-crunching approach is forced to do long division repeatedly.)