# Question deletion

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I was wondering why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166499/how-to-get-all-rows-from-arraylistarrayliststring-having-specific-value-in-s/) question was deleted without any reason. Although *they* closed it by stating it as *too broad*, I fail to understand the reason behind it. My understanding was cause maybe the OP didn't make an attempt to try to solve his question?

But I've seen MANY similar instances where the question had no attempt at all like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370314/mapx-listy-convert-to-mapy-listx-using-java-stream). Just curious as to why this wasn't closed as well. Isn't this too broad as well? Why is there an inconsistency? Is my understanding incorrect, what am I missing?

Screenshot of the question that was deleted :

[image]

Comment: Luck of the draw would be my guess. A poor question in a highly trafficed set of tags. Those tend to get cleaned up pretty quickly.

Comment: But that isn't fair is it? If you see the other question its on its way to being closed. (If you count the number of close votes). Why is that there is an inconsistency?

Comment: When you ask "why is crap question 1 closed, but crap question 2 stays open?", the answer is nearly always: because the people who vote to close questions cannot handle the volume of questions being asked.

Comment: What's **fair** got to do with it?...that's why I said "Luck".

Comment: Downvotes on Meta (which are by and large consequence-free) can indicate disagreement, be it with a proposal (in a [feature-request]) or with the premises or framing of a question (in a [discussion]).

Comment: In all fairness both should be closed. Likewise all similar questions where there is no attempt at all.

Comment: @NicholasK _"In all fairness both should be closed"_ We're working on it.

Comment: Now I do see that the question is closed. Now, who decides when it gets deleted? Does this mean that whenever such a scenario takes place is it the protocol to raise a question here to raise awareness?

Comment: @NicholasK It can't be user deleted before -3 score ATM.

Comment: It was brought up in a chat room.  Twice no less, first as "Too broad / no effort" and again by the same user 3 days later as "work dump w/ accepted answer".  That's invariably enough to seal its fate, lots of users are voting in that room and there are not there to celebrate good content.  There was some chitchat under your post, "you are so right.. when I answer such a question with no attempt, I get mercilessly down-voted.. feel sad that the community upvoted this question and this answer"  Used to be that SO had crappy questions with fantastic answers with a million Google hits.  The end.

Comment: @HansPassant : Ok to some extent I agree with you as to why it was closed. But the same should be applied universally is all I'm trying to say. Also say this were to happen again, whats the right way to handle it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : Sorry I didn't get that?

Comment: It's quite random, takes just one user that likes that room to get that ball rolling.  Life's not fair and all that.

Comment: @HansPassant : Haha. Just since you brought up that point of someone crying in a post under my answer. That very same someone goes and does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53311904/java-collection-set-for-user-defined-types-with-unique-key-strings/53312003#53312003).

Comment: There's a point to be made about visibility too. The deleted question screenshots shows 122 views. The non deleted question is at 77 views.... No wonder one was closed faster than the other if it attracted roughly twice the views

Comment: @Patrice : I don't mind it getting closed *for whatever reason*. My issue is why to delete it and keep an almost similar one active?

Comment: We'll I was addressing the fact you said 'this one was closed, this one isn't', by showcasing how much more visibility one had over the other. As to the deletion, I can't see the one deleted, so I don't know who or what deleted it.... If it's Roomba... Give it time, it'll get to the other one too, eventually

Comment: @Patrice : Thank you. No it wasn't Roomba.

Comment: @HansPassant : Here's another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405616/fill-the-object-with-multiple-equal-conditions/53405768#53405768) from the same user. My intention is not to get back at anyone, but just to ensure that rules are applied uniformly.

Comment: @NicolasK then I guess it was deleted by enough delete votes? Maybe it's the same thing as for close votes... The other one just hasn't attracted enough visibility. It's usually how this goes

Comment: @Patrice : I appreciate you time. Yes it got 3 delete votes. Also one last thing, what is the protocol to follow when things like this happen? It would really help.

Comment: With respect to the justification for closing the question, I tend to agree with you and Hans. [Lack of effort is not a close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367556/2751851).

Comment: @Nicolas normally the guidance is more around waiting for the community to do its thing. I fully support the intent of cleaning the site as quickly as possible (broken window theory and whatnot), so if you think its worth moving faster, then the close reviewers chat may be a good place to ping to increase visibility to people who care like you, and have the privileges to carry out what needs to be done. Do know though that it's very possible you will get disagreement there sometimes (not to say in this specific case)

Comment: @Patrice : What is the link for close reviewers?

Comment: https://socvr.org/

Comment: I'm disinclined to agree with the question closure, but I'm not hopping on the blame [the SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) train either. The first request was for closure, the second request was for deletion. It is left to the individual members to vote responsibly, and discuss requests that they think are erroneous. All members are accountable for their actions if/when such accountability is requested on meta. ...

Comment: ... I encourage any users that are knowledgeable of the topicality of Stack Overflow to join the room to discuss such requests and help everyone learn to be better reviewers. The SOCVR chat room is partly intended as a learning tool, as well as being a tool to expediate moderation action or make moderation action possible where it otherwise would not be.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> But I've seen MANY similar instances where the question had no attempt at all like this. Just curious as to why this wasn't closed as well. Isn't this too broad as well? Why is there an inconsistency? Is my understanding incorrect, what am I missing?

#### There is inconsistency because votes on questions (up-votes, down-votes, close-votes, reopen-votes, delete-votes, undelete-votes) are dealt by different users in the community, not by a script following a preset algorithm.

Not all questions are seen by the same users. Not all questions are seen by the same number of users. Whatever the guidelines say, not all users exactly agree on how we should be vote on each question.

E.g.: Users who follow different tags tend to have markedly different standards, although users who follow the same tag can and do disagree, vehemently many times. Users with different levels of experience with a technology, or with how Stack Overflow works can also have completely different opinions. Users sometimes just simply disagree about stuff. Etc.

**You shouldn't expect perfect consistency in a system that relies in the wisdom of the crowds.**

If you see two similar questions (at least in your opinion and from your point of view) that have been moderated in a very different manner, you need to understand that sometimes it's simply that one question had more views than the other, or than a question was asked at a different time, when moderation standards were different on the site.

And many other times, *it is simply a matter of luck*. Questions that attracts the right or the wrong crowd at a specific time, can be rewarded in very different ways.

Instead of asking about fairness, use your votes to try to moderate the site in a way that's consistent with the current curation standards according to your understanding.

That many poor quality questions remain open and haven't been deleted (*yet*) is not a justification **not to close & delete *other* poor quality questions**.

It's not about fairness: It's simply a matter of many more users asking question than users actively moderating the site.

As final note, regarding a question you raised in a comment:

> Now, who decides when it gets deleted?

Users in the community take those decisions. Check the [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page. On reaching 10k and 20K reputation, [you will be able to cast delete votes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)  on certain circumstances, among other things.

Comment: I'm ok with questions being closed. But for one to get deleted as too broad and the other to remain open is my concern.

Comment: I think I addressed the _why_ of that in my answer. Not sure what else I can do for you. You need to understand that the site is moderated by users of the community, and that logically that will imply a level of inconsistency. Not all users are going to think alike, and not all users are going to see all posts.

Comment: Yes agreed, thank you. *This is off-topic*, I noticed that the votes don't have an impact on the rep, any reason why?

Comment: By the same token: if lots of questions end up closed due to close reasons being misinterpreted, that is no reason to extend the misinterpretation to other questions.

Comment: @NicholasK Voting in [meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) is different.

Comment: @NicholasK: "*But for one to get deleted as too broad and the other to remain open is my concern.*" I don't see why this is concerning to you. Please do not start making Meta posts for *every* question you see that should be closed or deleted that isn't.

Comment: Just FYI: Delete-voting on questions that have been closed/on hold for > 2 days is a [10k privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). The [20k delete-vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) is for answers with score < 0 and closed questions with score < -2 (without the need to wait 2 days after the question is closed).

Comment: Thanks @Makyen. Those privileges are still a long way to go for me, far enough to get them wrong from down here. :)

Comment: np. It's easy to mix-up those two privileges. People mix them up all the time. You're getting up there. One of the big differences at 10k is seeing deleted posts, but you can usually get them from Google's cache or archive.org. You just have to keep plugging away at posting questions and answers. It is, however, a lot of work/time/effort.

Comment: @NicolBolas : Obviously, that's why I've asked the right way to handle such a scenario.