# Can we hold competitons?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

On Russian SO, we have special tag "Competition" for users to try out their skills to create some special program. For example, make less code, improve it, or solve a special problem. I tried to find something like that here, but couldn't. Is it possible to hold such competitions? I think it would be interesting for users to try out how do they know their language.
Example question(from ruSO):

### Hello world with empty main function

Faced such a task at the interview:

> Write a program that prints the phrase Hello world to the console

And everything would be fine if there was a point after that. But the phrase goes on:

> provided that the main () function of this program is as follows:

```
int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean, like [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @fbueckert Oh, we have a special SE site for that... ok.

Comment: @fbueckert But can we make it on SO?

Comment: We attract 35 times more questions per day. No time for fun. Sorry, gotta go.

Comment: @fbueckert codegolf requires winning criteria, so each programming language has only about 1 answer (which is already too many).

Comment: Suggestions for future meta feature requests: try to explain how implementing the feature you have in mind would help the site. Stack, due to its size and traffic, has a lot of momentum to be resistant to change. 'because I think it would be fun' (which is what I understand your reasoning is here) isn't the greatest of reasons.

Comment: Many of us hate the whole idea of "competitive programming".

Comment: see also: [Burninate \[code-golf\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274984/839601)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**TL;DR** No, thank you.

This would be *extremely* difficult to moderate on a site of this size. As [Makoto pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377645/2057919), this site gets a tremendous amount of traffic. Users post about 8,000 questions per day on average (lower on weekends and higher during the week). Many of those questions are already of poor quality. So, imagine if this word got out:

> Hey, there's a special tag on Stack Overflow. Just tag your post `competition`, and people will compete to write code for you! Just don't tell them it's your homework.

Add into that all the new and creative forms of spam and other abuse we would see. It would simply be unworkable.

Keep in mind that this also would have several other negative effects. Users only have so much time to spend on answering questions. By adding a "competition" category of posts, distinguished only by a particular tag, we would:

1. make traditional, non-competition questions compete against competition questions for attention, and
2. require people who want to answer questions to spend more time *finding* the questions they want to answer.

End results:

- Much, much more homework and job-interview spam.
- Lots of questions showing no effort, but getting away with it by pretending to be about a competition of some sort.
- A surge in people trying to cheat in other, off-site competitions (which already happens fairly frequently).
- Fewer answers on good, traditional questions.
- A slow erosion of question and answer quality as new users get even more confused about what kinds of posts are on-topic and appropriate.
- Skewed reputation effects. (Compare the insane things that happened with reputation when we had Documentation.)

All in all, I think this would be a bad idea for this site.

---

None of this is to say that I'm opposed to coding competitions, [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) (where I have an account and have competed several times), [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) (where I also have a somewhat active account), and so on. I'm not even opposed to the competitions on Russian SO. If that works, more power to that community. It's just not realistic on *this* site, *i.e.*, Stack Overflow (English edition).

Answer (score 15):

Stack Overflow is too big to do something like this in an effective and cleanly moderated way.  Smaller sites like the language-specific SOs could pull this off since there's not much traffic on a given day, and the communities are a bit more tight-knit.  On SO, though, since we see something between 3.9 and 4.1 million hits per day *over the weekend* (and that balloons to something north of 10M during the week), there's no guarantee that we'd be able to cleanly run one of these.

Comment: Views are not the important statistic, [the number of questions](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questions) is. A view does not need anything; each new question needs reading and voting, and then flagging or answering. (That is where my "35 times" alludes to.)